# Unable to upload to s3 using Boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I found a script on [github](https://gist.github.com/SavvyGuard/6115006) to upload a folder to S3 using B

```
import boto
import boto.s3

import os.path
import sys

# Fill these in - you get them when you sign up for S3
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET = ''
# Fill in info on data to upload
# destination bucket name
bucket_name = 'jwu-testbucket'
# source directory
sourceDir = 'testdata/'
# destination directory name (on s3)
destDir = ''

#max size in bytes before uploading in parts. between 1 and 5 GB recommended
MAX_SIZE = 20 * 1000 * 1000
#size of parts when uploading in parts
PART_SIZE = 6 * 1000 * 1000

conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET)

bucket = conn.create_bucket(bucket_name,
        location=boto.s3.connection.Location.DEFAULT)


uploadFileNames = []
for (sourceDir, dirname, filename) in os.walk(sourceDir):
    uploadFileNames.extend(filename)
    break

def percent_cb(complete, total):
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()

for filename in uploadFileNames:
    sourcepath = os.path.join(sourceDir + filename)
    destpath = os.path.join(destDir, filename)
    print 'Uploading %s to Amazon S3 bucket %s' % \
           (sourcepath, bucket_name)

    filesize = os.path.getsize(sourcepath)
    if filesize > MAX_SIZE:
        print "multipart upload"
        mp = bucket.initiate_multipart_upload(destpath)
        fp = open(sourcepath,'rb')
        fp_num = 0
        while (fp.tell() < filesize):
            fp_num += 1
            print "uploading part %i" %fp_num
            mp.upload_part_from_file(fp, fp_num, cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10, size=PART_SIZE)

        mp.complete_upload()

    else:
        print "singlepart upload"
        k = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket)
        k.key = destpath
        k.set_contents_from_filename(sourcepath,
                cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10)
```

When running it I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upload_to_s3.py", line 29, in <module>
    bucket = conn.create_bucket(bucket_name, location=boto.s3.connection.Location.DEFAULT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 613, in create_bucket
    data=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 665, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1071, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1030, in _mexe
    raise ex
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I changed the DEFAULT to "s3-eu-west-1" doesn't work and I removed completly the DEFAULT to make it like this:

```
bucket = conn.create_bucket(bucket_name)
```

and I got an error also.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you change the connection command to use `conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('eu-west-1', ...)`?

`boto.s3.connection.Location.EU` instead of DEFAULT might also be worth a try - I'm not sure how you were using "s3-eu-west-1". (As a string?)

Comment: Can you even resolve the endpoints? Try `ping s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: ` 64 bytes from s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (54.231.131.83): icmp_seq=1 ttl=44 time=24.7 ms `